# How do you import texture packs in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is a reliable website to download texture packs from? Also, how do you import the texture packs into an offline world in Minecraft?

Comment: The first part of your question is a bit off topic (in the realm of shopping recommendations), but one of the best places to start is probably the Minecraft forums.

Comment: The [Texture Pack article at Minecraft Wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Texture_pack) answers both your questions. I'm obliged to downvote your question for lacking evidence of research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Texture packs go in your texture pack folder. There are two ways to get to this on a Windows machine:

Open up Minecraft and go to `Options > Texture Packs > Open texture pack folder`

OR

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type in `%appdata%` and click OK, then open the `.minecraft` folder (this is usually, but not always, at the top of the list). Then open the `texturepacks` folder.

Simply put the file you downloaded in this folder and select it in-game from the Texture Packs menu.

As for where to download them, I'd suggest starting at the [official forums texture packs section](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/41-texture-packs/), or downloading the [Curse client](http://www.curse.com/client) and getting them through that.

Comment: Is this current?